# Definite integral of $y=x$ and $y=\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}$

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

So I got the following problem :

Calculate the area of the domain between the curves $y=x, \; y=\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}$ and the horizontal lines $y=1$ and $y=2$. I think that the answer is $\frac{1}{2}$.

I basically evaluated the following integral :

integral of $\frac{1}{y^2}$ from $1$ to $2$. I didn't include the $y=x$ because it didn't delimit the area I'm supposed to calculate. (Graph the two curves to see better my reasoning)

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is your region:

[image]

The easiest is to integrate with respect to the y axis. The red line is $f(y)=y$, the black curve is $g(y)=\dfrac{1}{y^2}$

$$A=\int_1^2 \ f(y)-g(y) \ dy$$

Comment: Ok, I found 1. Is it correct ?

Comment: yes 1 is correct @Astroman